# Probability the 13th card dealt is the first king dealt?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, uniform-distribution, card-games

The problem:

> A player is randomly dealt 13 cards from a standard 52-card deck. What is the probability the 13th card dealt is the first king dealt?

I understand the solution which is based on the Total Probability Theorem which is the following:

> We need to count the number of ways to get 12 cards so that there is exactly one king in the deck. There are $48 \choose 12$ ways of doing this. So the probability of getting this is $\frac{48 \choose 12}{52 \choose 13}$. Next we can choose one out of 4 kings with probability $\frac{1}{13}$ which makes the total probability $4 \cdot \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{48 \choose 12}{52 \choose 13}$.

**What I don't understand is why we can't just use counting to calculate probability here?** We know that sample space is uniformly distributed, so we just need to count the total number of ways to get 13 cards out of 52 which is $52 \choose 13$ and the number of decks where the king is the last one which should be equal to $4 \cdot \frac{48 \choose 12}{52 \choose 13}$. Then divide the numbers.

Would appreciate any help to get an intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it this way.

The total number of orders is $13! \binom{52}{13}$ - no issues there.

To construct a "successful" ordering, you need to first pick a set of $13$ cards that has exactly one king, then make sure that the king is actually the $13$th card. There are $4$ ways to choose the king (pick its suit), and then $\binom{52 - 4}{12} = \binom{48}{12}$ ways to pick the other cards. The number of orders is thus $12! (4) \binom{48}{12}$ - here we are multiplying by $12!$ because we know *the king has to go last*. We only have freedom to permute the other (non-king) cards.

The probability is thus $P = \frac{12! (4) \binom{48}{12}}{13! \binom{52}{13}} = \frac{4 \binom{48}{12}}{13 \binom{52}{13}}$, as desired.

The problem with your approach is that you do not consider that the king has to be the *last* of the $13$ cards in the order.

Your answer would be right had the question been, "What is the probability that exactly one king is drawn within the first $13$ cards?"

Comment: Okay, this is an unordered vs ordered selection, got it. Thank you very much, it is a bit tricky to notice.